# Is it possible to have instead mypage.com/?page_id=81 to have mypage.com/cool/?

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to have instead mypage.com/?page_id=81 (this is just an example, I am talking about all these pages with long custom links) to have mypage.com/cool/ ? Are there any plugins to achieve this? I used a plugin page links to, but it just links whatever to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Settings > Permalinks and activate permalinks. Follow all the steps including the `.htaccess` changes.

You can then change the permalink on the post/page edit page, right under the title.